# How can I convert this contact form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have one contact form that I want to convert it in rails. I have created the same form in rails but I want to add its special classes like data-error-empty, data-ok-message and data-error-invalid.

Here is the form that I want to convert in rails

```
<form  id="contact-form" class="bl_form text-center" action="contact.php" method="post" novalidate>
                    <span class="field-wrap scrollimation fade-right">
                        <label class="control-label" for="contact-name">Name</label>
                        <input id="contact-name" name="contactName" type="text" class="label_better requiredField" data-new-placeholder="Name" placeholder="Name" data-error-empty="*Enter your name">
                    </span>
                    <span class="field-wrap scrollimation fade-in">
                        <label class="control-label" for="contact-mail">Email</label>
                        <input id="contact-mail" name="email" type="email" class="label_better requiredField" data-new-placeholder="Email Address" placeholder="Email Address" data-error-empty="*Enter your email" data-error-invalid="x Invalid email address">
                    </span>
                    <span class="field-wrap scrollimation fade-left">
                        <label class="control-label" for="contact-message">Message</label>
                        <textarea id="contact-message" name="comments" rows="1" class="label_better requiredField" data-new-placeholder="Message" placeholder="Message" data-error-empty="*Enter your message"></textarea>
                    </span>

                    <p class="text-center"><button  name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-meflat icon-left" data-error-message="Error!" data-sending-message="Sending..." data-ok-message="Message Sent"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Send Message</button></p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />

                </form>
```

And here is the form I created in rails.

```
  <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :message %>
          <%= f.text_area :message, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
      <% end %>
```

Also how can I add the form on the homepage the form url in rails is contacts/new. Thank you.

Comment: Just try {data-error-empty: "data cannot be empty", data-error-invalid:"Invalid data"} as the last parameter... also you can try partial for the rendering the form at 2 places

Comment: @sethi its not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after working for hours I found the answer. Here is the code that worked.

```
<%= form_for @contact, id: 'new_contact', class: 'new_contact text-center', url: contact_path, method: :post do |f| %>
                <span class="field-wrap scrollimation fade-right">
                        <label class="control-label" for="contact_name">Name</label>
                        <input id="contact-name" name="contact[name]" type="text" class="label_better requiredField" data-new-placeholder="Name" placeholder="Name" data-error-empty="*Enter your name">
                    </span>
                    <span class="field-wrap scrollimation fade-in">
                        <label class="control-label" for="contact_email">Email</label>
                        <input id="contact-mail" name="contact[email]" type="email" class="label_better requiredField" data-new-placeholder="Email Address" placeholder="Email Address" data-error-empty="*Enter your email" data-error-invalid="x Invalid email address">
                    </span>
                    <span class="field-wrap scrollimation fade-left">
                        <label class="control-label" for="contact_message">Message</label>
                        <textarea id="contact-message" name="contact[message]" rows="1" class="label_better requiredField" data-new-placeholder="Message" placeholder="Message" data-error-empty="*Enter your message"></textarea>
                    </span>

                    <p class="text-center"><button  name="commit" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm icon-left" data-error-message="Error!" data-sending-message="Sending..." data-ok-message="Message Sent"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Send Message</button></p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
             <% end %>
```